# SLI Connector for different Mobos

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, sli

Can I use an SLI connector from MSI in a GIGABYTE motherboard? Are they standard?

Actually I've done this but somehow NVidia control doesn't show "Enable SLI" choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SLI Bridge is motherboard (and video card) independent, feel free to re-use anywhere - the only reason you sometimes get them is (as below) it can be different lengths, but if it fits - feel free to reuse.

[image]

Comment: I guess a picture is worth more than the same answer + more content, lol

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the connector should work fine. Check that your connections are tight. Make sure there isn't anything you need to do to enable SLI via the Gigabyte mobo (ie a Bios setting). Consult the Mobo's manual on this.